# Can $\mathrm{tan}$ be defined by an IVP with rational functions as coefficients?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry, definition

We can define $\sin$ and $\cos$ as the solutions to the DE $$f''(x) = -f(x)$$ subject to certain initial conditions.

The above DE has constant coefficients, but I'd like to use a similar approach to defining $\tan$, and I'm happy generalize to rational functions, for example $$f''(x) = x^3 f'(x) -\frac{3x}{1-x^2} f(x)$$ would be a valid candidate.

Anyway:

> **Question.** Can $\mathrm{tan}$ be defined by an IVP with rational functions as coefficients?

Note that $$f'(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$$ is solved by $f(x) = \mathrm{arctan}(x),$ so that's a near miss.

Comment: Something like $1+(f)^2=f'$ would be out of the question as it's nonlinear right?

Comment: @ZacharySelk, yes, but that's a nice solution to a related problem. Nice one :)

Comment: I answered and I'm pretty sure my answer is in spirit right but the details I messed up. Basically, derivatives of $\tan(x)$ are just polynomials in $\tan(x)$ with integer coefficients. See my deleted half answer.

Comment: @ZacharySelk, interesting link! It hadn't occurred that this was possible.

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2314942/finding-the-nth-derivative-of-functions-in-particular-y-tanx) finds non-linear DE for $n\in\{1,\dots,9\}$. It doesn't seem promising from that and [this pdf](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1202.1205v1.pdf) that there's a linear DE for it, but I'm unclear how you'd prove that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Functions which can be defined in this way are said to be [holonomic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomic_function), and $\tan x$ is known not to be holonomic. This is because holonomic functions have finitely many singularities (the singularities of the denominators of the rational functions involved), while $\tan x$ has infinitely many singularities.

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense.